# passing data object through @Output

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-output

I'm not getting any errors, but the data isn't passing through to the parent component.  The way I'm doing it is a bit different from all the examples I've been finding online so I'm already not too sure about how I have it set up.  Here's the code so far.

How I'm calling it in the `Child Component`

```
//a variable that stores the fetched data from a group of radio buttons
selected = {value1: '', value2: ''};

//the output variable
@Output() selectedO: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public sendAnswer = (): void => {
     this.selectedO.emit(this.selected);
 }
```

The Input in the `Child Component` Template

```
<input type="radio"
    [attr.name]  = "quesForm.value.name"
    [attr.id]    = "ans.id"
    [attr.value] = "ans.answer"
    (click)      = "getSelected(ans)" //fetches data I want to pass
    (click)      = "sendAnswer()"    //sets fetched data to @Output
    hidden
/>
```

How I'm calling it in the `Parent Component` template

```
<multiple-choice-radio *ngIf="expbTrigger"
    [question]="question01"
    (selectedO)="selectedI" //where I'm trying to pull the data into parent component
 ></multiple-choice-radio>
```

How I'm callign it in the `Parent Component`

```
public selectedI(selected) {
    this.selectedII = selected;
}

selectedII: any; //the variable I'm trying to store it into
```

This is the best way I could rationalize to try to make this all work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event binding doesn't assign or call if you provide a field or method name, it just executes the expression. The expression therefore needs to include the assignment or call. `$event` references the emitted value.

```
(selectedO)="selectedI = $event" // field
```

or

```
(selectedO)="selectedI($event)" // method
```

Comment: am I suppose to add that to the template of the parent component's template?  I just did that it's still not loading values.

Comment: Instead of `(selectedO)="selectedI"`

Comment: I updated my answer. `selectedI` is a method, not a property.

Comment: GREAT THAT WORKS!!!  I have to wait 7 more minutes to select answer though, thanks, turns out I was closer than I thought lol.